# newly added routes not working with nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have my laravel app configured with nginx. My existing routes are working without any issues. But my newly added routes are not working with nginx.

Here is my nginx.conf

```
server
  {
     listen 80;
     server_name app.dev.com;
     root /apps/php/webdev/myapp/public;
     index index.php index.html index.htm;
     try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

     location @rewrite
     {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
        #index index.php;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
     }
    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
       fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }
    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root /apps/php/webdev/myapp/public;
        }
     location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Here is my part of routes.

```
Route::group(['before' => 'adminAccess'], function() {
    // Logs
    Route::get('logs',                              ['as' => 'log',                 'uses' => 'LogController@getLogsByApp']);
    Route::post('logs',                             ['as' => 'export.log',          'uses' => 'LogController@export']);

   Route::get('staffs',                 ['as' => 'staffs.index',             'uses' => 'StaffsController@index']);
   Route::get('staffs/new',             ['as' => 'staffs.new',         'uses' => 'StaffsController@create']);
   Route::post('staffs/new',            ['as' => 'staffs.new',         'uses' => 'StaffsController@store']);
   Route::get('staffs/{staffId}/delete',['as' => 'staffs.delete',      'uses' => 'StaffsController@destroy']);
   Route::get('staffs/{staffId}',       ['as' => 'staffs.detail',      'uses' => 'StaffsController@show']);
   Route::put('staffs/{staffId}',      ['as' => 'staffs.update',      'uses' => 'StaffsController@update']);
   Route::get('staffs/{staffId}/edit', ['as' => 'staffs.edit',      'uses' => 'StaffsController@edit']);


    // Portal Users
    Route::get('users',                             ['as' => 'portal.users',        'uses' => 'PortalUsersController@getIndex']);
    Route::get('user/new',                          ['as' => 'portal.users.new',    'uses' => 'PortalUsersController@getCreate']);
    Route::post('user/new',                         ['as' => 'portal.users.store',  'uses' => 'PortalUsersController@doCreate']);
    Route::get('user/delete',                       ['as' => 'portal.user.delete',  'uses' => 'PortalUsersController@doDelete']);
    Route::get('user/{userId}/edit',                ['as' => 'portal.user.edit',    'uses' => 'PortalUsersController@getEdit']);
    Route::post('user/{userId}/edit',               ['as' => 'portal.user.update',  'uses' => 'PortalUsersController@doEdit']);
});
```

Here, My newly added Staffs routes are not working, But other routes are working.

Comment: is this laravel 5? can you paste your routes?

Comment: @TzookBarNoy, I have updated with my routes.

Comment: all looks good, but please go to yoursite.com/staffs and add what is your error....

Comment: Hey I did not get any error

Comment: So what exactly do you get?? Share more details

Comment: Hey @TzookBarNoy, Issue resolved. It was not nginx config issue. Old code was giving us 404 instead of 403, So we thought its a config issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AbibullahRahamathulah Please answer your own question with the details about the config issue and how you solved it. It might be useful for other people having the same struggle and visiting this post. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @lukasgeiter, Its not the config issue. Still I will answer my question with the details of my issue. Thanks